# Publicações automaticas instagram php

Tags: php, api, instagram-api

Estou com dificuldades em desenvolver um *script php* para fazer publicações automáticas no ***Instagram***, o mesmo tem uma *API* para estas publicações, com suporte para operações de *CRUD*, mas para isso, é necessário que eu faça parte do *closed beta Facebook Marketing Partner*s ou *Instagram Partners*, que no caso eu não consegui permissão, pois não estão aceitando novos partners...

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma solução, ou conseguiu estas permissões de alguma forma!

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar essa API: https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API

Aqui tem um exemplo de como fazer upload de uma foto para o Instagram:

```
<?php
require '../src/Instagram.php';
/////// CONFIG ///////
$username = '';
$password = '';
$debug    = false;
$photo    = '';     // path to the photo
$caption  = null;   // caption
//////////////////////
$i = new Instagram($username, $password, $debug);
try{
  $i->login();
} catch (InstagramException $e)
{
  $e->getMessage();
  exit();
}
try {
  $i->uploadPhoto($photo, $caption);
} catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Muitissimo obrigado pela resposta amigo!